# Navigation Items not clicking

Tags: java, android

Nothing happens when I click on the items "Orders" and "Logout" from my navigation drawer:

[image]

Here's my code for the navigation drawer:

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference category;
    TextView txtFullName;
    RecyclerView recycler_menu;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Menu");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        category = database.getReference("Category");
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent cartIntent = new Intent(Home.this, Cart.class);
                startActivity(cartIntent);
            }
        });
        
        final DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
                        drawer.closeDrawers();

                        int id = menuItem.getItemId();

                        if (id == R.id.nav_menu) {
                            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "menu Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (id == R.id.nav_cart) {
                            Intent cartIntent = new Intent(Home.this, Cart.class);
                            startActivity(cartIntent);
                        } else if (id == R.id.nav_orders) {
//                            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Order Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent orderIntent = new Intent(Home.this, OrderStatus.class);
                            startActivity(orderIntent);
                        } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
                            //Logout
                            Intent signIn=new Intent(Home.this,SignIn.class);
                            signIn.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(signIn);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });

        //set name for user
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        txtFullName = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
        txtFullName.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());

        //load menu
        recycler_menu = findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
        recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        loadMenu();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

    private void loadMenu() {
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Category> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Category>()
                .setQuery(category, Category.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(options) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.menu_item, parent, false);
                return new MenuViewHolder(itemView);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuViewHolder viewHolder, int position, @NonNull Category model) {
                viewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage())
                        .into(viewHolder.imageView);
                final Category clickItem = model;
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Intent foodList = new Intent(Home.this, FoodList.class);
                        foodList.putExtra("CategoryId", adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                        startActivity(foodList);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
        super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

I've tried to add toast in the `nav_orders` to check when I click orders it toast up but didn't work too, Code I've tried is :

```
else if (id == R.id.nav_orders) {
    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Order Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: can you share your nav graph xml file?

Comment: which xml layout u need?

Comment: the navigation graph related to this code under res/navigation directory

Comment: you mean this ? https://www.codepile.net/pile/p0go7B06

Comment: But is the method onNavigationItemSelected called?

Answer (score 0):

If you have orders and logouts as items not under groups in drawer_menu you can create `onClickListner` for them. Don't call them by using if condition. You can directly place them under `public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)`.

This sholud look like:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new HomeFragment()).commit();
            toolbar.setTitle("Ongoing Events");
            break;
        case R.id.nav_category:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new HistoryFragment()).commit();
            toolbar.setTitle("History");
            break;
        case R.id.Orders:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Orders", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        case R.id.nav_logout:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    (MainActivity.this));
            builder.setTitle("Logout?");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to sign out?");
            builder.setNegativeButton("NO",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                        }
                    });
            builder.setPositiveButton("YES",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                            logout();
                            restart();
                        }
                    });
            builder.show();
            break;

    }
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: i should implement fragment before?

Comment: If you don't have any fragments then you can simply just use remove fragments part from my answer and use it to jump  to show toasts. see in my another answer and please upvote me that would be very kind of you!